# How do I perform Complex Event Processing using Esper with streams coming from CSV data?

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, complex-event-processing, esper

I am sending CSV rows continuously to Kafka topics using a Kafka producer and generating a stream of CSV rows of the following form:

```
temp=23.3, pressure=1015, humidity=63.4, windspeed=7.4.....
```

Now, I want to perform complex event processing on this stream using ESPER, but Esper uses pre-defined POJO class and uses EPL statement for filtering the events.

How do I transform the CSV streams to Event streams at run-time such that Esper can extract or filter the parameters like temp or pressure based on some logic (for example extract parameters which are changing over 5 minutes time period)?

Answer (score 1):

Sample code follows. This sample assumes there are already some messages in the topic. This does not loop and wait for more messages.

```
    Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ip);
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
    KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> rows = consumer.poll(1000);
    Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> it = rows.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> row = it.next();
        MyEvent event = new MyEvent(row.value()); // transform string to event

        // process event
        runtime.sendEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: This will work. Instead of using the StringDeserializer, you could also register a value deserializer that directly converts from bytes to your event type.